# ReferenceError: Item Is Not Defined In NodeJs Route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I define my API routes in Nodejs but when I run it, it gives this error message.

**Error Message**

> ReferenceError: Item is not defined
>
> ```
> at D:\shoppinglist\serverside\route\routes.js:7:5
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> at Function.process_params (D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
> at next (D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
> at Function.handle (D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
> at router (D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at trim_prefix (D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
> at D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
> at Function.process_params (D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
> at next (D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
> at jsonParser (D:\shoppinglist\serverside\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:110:7)
> ```

**My Route.js code is**

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/items', (req, res, next)=>{
    Item.find(function(err, items){
        if(err){
            res.json(err);
        }
        else{
            res.json(items);
        }
    });
});
router.post('/item', (req, res, next)=>{
    let newShoppingItem = new Item({
        itemName: req.body.itemName,
        itemQuantity: req.body.itemQuantity,
        itemBought: req.body.itemBought
    });
    newShoppingItem.save((err, item)=>{
        if(err){
            res.json(err)
        }
        else{
            res.json({msg: 'Item has been added to db'});
        }
    });
});
router.put('/put_test', (req, res, next)=>{
  // do later
});

router.delete('/delete_test', (req, res, next)=>{
  // do later
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my shoopingitem.js code

**shoppingitem.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const shoppingItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    itemName:{
        type: String,
        require:true
    },

    itemQuantity:{
        type: Number,
        require:true
    },

    itemBought:{
        type: Boolean,
        require:true
    },

});
const Item = module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', shoppingItemSchema);
```

Please suggest me the solution. I'm new in nodejs. So please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Matthew Weeks, be sure to import the mongoose Item model into your Route.js file.

Also if you're trying to query all items from a collection, be sure to include an empty query object as the first parameter in the find function. Including Matthew Weeks solution, the first part of Route.js should look something like:

```
const Item = require('../path/to/item/shoppingItem.js');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/items', (req, res, next)=>{
Item.find({}, function(err, items){
    if(err){
        res.json(err);
    }
    else{
        res.json(items);
    }
});
```

Comment: #Leo Gordillo thanks for answer but now it gives a message Error: Cannot find module '../path/to/item/shoppingItem.js'  how I reslove this issue please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to require the Item model into the routes file in order to use it. This can be done in 2 ways:

```
const Item = require('../path/to/item/shoppingItem.js')
```

or

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Item = mongoose.model('Item');
```